# Passing big arguments in change-making problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have problem with change-making problem algorithm. 
My function coin_change_solutions works well with small numbers. 
For example if we pass [1,10,25] as coins and 32 as S (change that we want to get) it will return [10,10,10,1,1]. Problem occurs when I want to pass bigger numbers as I want to operate on cents, not on dollars so that I have fixed-point arithmetic (it's a must because operating on floating-point arithmetic won't be a good idea later on). 
So when I pass an array with all the denominations in cents [1,5,10,25,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,10000,50000] and 50000 as change my compiler stops and doesn't show any result.

Do you know what should I do so that the algorithm has high efficiency and can be passed all the nominals in cents?

```py
def coin_change_solutions(coins, S):
  # create an S x N table for memoization
  N = len(coins)
  sols = [[[] for n in range(N + 1)] for s in range(S + 1)]
  for n in range(0, N + 1):
    sols[0][n].append([])

  # fill table using bottom-up dynamic programming
  for s in range(1, S+1):
    for n in range(1, N+1):
      without_last = sols[s][n - 1]
      if (coins[n - 1] <= s):
          with_last = [list(sol) + [coins[n-1]] for sol in sols[s - coins[n - 1]][n]]
      else:
          with_last = []
      sols[s][n] = without_last + with_last
  x = min(sols[S][N], key=len)


  return x
```

Comment: It looks like you're generating *every single possible way* to make change. You don't need to do that.

Comment: `for s in range(1, S+1):` number of iterations are 50000 * 12, run the code now, check for the answer tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

Not the solution to your query, but a better solution with less space:

```
dp = [0] + [float('inf') for i in range(S)]
for i in range(1, S+1):
    for coin in coins:
        if i - coin >= 0:
            dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i-coin] + 1)
if dp[-1] == float('inf'):
    return -1
return dp[-1]
```

Assume `dp[i]` is the fewest number of coins making up amount `S`, then for every coin in `coins`, `dp[i] = min(dp[i - coin] + 1)`.

The time complexity is `O(amount * coins.length)` and the space complexity is `O(amount)`.